# Display extensions content in a sidebar in google extensions

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to do this? An extension which displays its contents in a sidebar instead of a dropdown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [Sidebar API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/experimental.sidebar.html), but it is experimental.

```
chrome.experimental.sidebar.navigate({path: "popup.html"})
```